# Add wysiwyg editor in WordPress textarea Meta Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm creating a repeatable meta box using this code below. how can i add a wysiwyg editor in this textarea field . any help is very much appreciated

[How to create meta box using clone ajax and jquery in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005482/how-to-create-meta-box-using-clone-ajax-and-jquery-in-wordpress#new-answer)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is an old question but maybe someone else might need it, so here is how you do it:

```
<textarea id="tag-description"></textarea>
```

First let the document load, then check if tinyMCE present and initialize the editor.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object") {
        tinyMCE.init({
            selector: '#tag-description'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow! super easy and superb solution. Is TinyMCE already included within WP? So amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the class 'theEditor' to your textarea.

```
<textarea class=”theEditor” name=’blurb’ id=’blurb’></textarea>
```

Edit:

You can also add editor with js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#blurb").addClass("mceEditor");
    if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" &&
         typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "blurb");
    }
});
</script>

<textarea class="" name='blurb' id='blurb'></textarea>
```

Comment: You need to use ``"`` not ``”`` or ``’``

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using a more recent version of tinyMCE. Change

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "blurb");
```

with

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, "blurb");
```